# Encrypted network share for multiple users

Tags: nfs, network-share, encryption

I have the following scenario:

- 100GB of data
- 5 users
- should be mounted on two different servers
- the servers are all running Ubuntu
- users are accessing/writing to it at the same time (not the same files)

What are my options? I looked into ecryptfs and Truecrypt. Both are not really suitable for multi user environments.

The user authentication on the servers itself is done via LDAP right now but it wouldn't be a problem to manually add users to the system if that's needed.

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to encrypt the network traffic or the data on disk?

Comment: Both should be encrypted.